# Continuous Deployment System

Tags: system, continuous-deployment

We have just set up TeamCity to build all of our projects and we need a system to deploy them to our staging and testing servers. The projects are ASP.NET. We also need to deploy our databases, is there something out there that can do this?

Thanks in advance. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn) looks like it would cover the deployment of the ASP.NET application code from TeamCity

As for databases, I am assuming you mean setting up TeamCity to run new database migration scripts.  You can run post build events in TeamCity but it depends on how you configure the build.  If you use MSBuild for instance you can do something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2008/08/15/bundle-sql-script-with-build-process-using-msbuild.aspx).  The other build runners like Nant should have something similar.  Hope this helps